Induced homomorphism on homology groups
Given a topological space $X$ with subspaces $A \subset B \subset X$ the identity mapping $\text{id}: X \longrightarrow X$ induces a map of pairs $\text{id}_\#: (X,A) \longrightarrow (X,B)$. What can we say about the induced homomorphism on the homology groups ${\text{id}_\#}_* :  H_n(X,A) \longrightarrow H_n(X,B)$?
I think that ${\text{id}_\#}_*$ should be an injection or an inclusion but am not sure.

What examples have you looked at?

I haven't looked at any examples yet. Are you suggesting there are examples which contradict that ${\text{id}#}*$ is an injection or inclusion?

I’m suggesting that examples are always good things to look at, if you want to understand a general situation. Look at examples, formulate a guess based on those examples, and then try to prove it.
